# Is there a way to invoke the gevent-socketio BaseNamespace.emit server side

Tags: socket.io, gevent-socketio

Is there a way to invoke the gevent-socketio BaseNamespace.emit on the server side since it uses environ['socketio'] to get the socket from the request.environ. How I can generate new virtual socket or emualate somehow the environ['socketio'] on the server so I can use it to invoke the gevent-socketio BaseNamespace class (for emitting a message for example).

The idea behind this is that the server itself would be able to broadcast messages on a fixed period.

Thanks